# Basic commands for Youtube-DL

Tags: command-line, audio, cmd.exe, youtube, youtube-dl

So I recently installed youtube-dl for the sole purpose of downloading music.
Unfortunately I don't currently have time to learn it.

So what i am asking for is a few basic commands that i can use to download any music video to a directory using the highest quality possible. I am interested in audio only. I don't know what codec and containers its possible to get, but all the popular ones work for me.

Another thing i am really interested in is downloading a playlist, again highest possible quality audio, in a respective directory. So what are the commands required to do these things? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at youtube-dl's man page?

Comment: "Unfortunately I don't currently have time to learn it." We don't have time to teach you.

Comment: I do like how the first reason on the downvote button is "This question does not show any research effort." Couldn't have put it better myself.

Comment: Its actually not like that. When I originally installed youtube-dl i looked up the launch parameters, which i found pretty confusing (given i haven't really worked with many programs on cmd). So after downloading a few videos to yet to be found locations, and not quite getting the audio seperated from the video, I gave up due to lack of time to invest into it. Yes i did some research effort, no it wasn't enough, but that's the reason I posted it here. When i get time i'd sure like to learn how to use the program in depth.

Comment: DavidPostill That's the purpose of forums, if there's something i know and you don't i'd happily show you. This time however i was just looking for some tips to get startet with youtube-dl quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also download the mp3 directly from youtube without converting using ffmpeg

`youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 <video URL>`

From the online help:

```
-x, --extract-audio        convert video files to audio-only files (requires
                           ffmpeg or avconv and ffprobe or avprobe)
```

Bear in mind as well that youtube-dl defaults to using avconv so you should consider specifying either avconv or FFmpeg at the commandline . From the online help :

```
--prefer-avconv                  Prefer avconv over ffmpeg for running the
                                 postprocessors (default)
--prefer-ffmpeg                  Prefer ffmpeg over avconv for running the
                                 postprocessors
```

Further options for keeping the original video, adjusting the bitrate or quality of the audio and a few others can be seen by looking at `youtube-dl -h` .

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/178991/606063)